# MySQL Order of Operations?

Tags: mysql

Is there a definitive place to find order of operations for mySQL statements?  Is the below order correct?

FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause

If this is the case, can I use a term defined in the SELECT clase (select first_name as "f_name") within the group by clause?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use an alias in the `having` clause in MySQL unlike in SQL Server. Not sure if that means that the logical order of operations is any different though.

Comment: [See this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/sql-server-join-where-processing-order/5040#5040)

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are interested in `SELECT`, according to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) the syntax is as follows

```
SELECT
[ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
  [HIGH_PRIORITY]
  [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
  [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
  [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
select_expr [, select_expr ...]
[FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
[HAVING where_condition]
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ...]
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
[PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
[INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
  | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
  | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
[FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Yes, you can use columns defined with `AS` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that, but if he really does then the query plan is completely up to the optimizer.

Comment: I think the issue here is being able to select as many records as possible so long as the user IDs are unique.

Comment: This is actually helpful to me. I was confused about ORDER BY and GROUP BY order when writing a query. Thank you.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Yes, this is the syntax for writing a query, but that's not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think Order By comes before Select (you can sort on a column you haven't selected), but Group By and Having come dead last for sure. Grouping requires knowledge of the entire result set, and you can only group on non-aggregate columns in the Select list (and you must group on ALL of them). Once the result set is grouped, Having is applied as a set of conditions to the grouped result set.

So, I think most engines, including MySQL, process as follows:

- Define domain source (FROM clause including JOINs)
- Filter (WHERE)
- Sort (ORDER BY)
- Project (SELECT)
- Group (GROUP BY)
- Filter again (HAVING)

Comment: You might want to compare your list with [this one for SQL Server](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf). That one has `ORDER BY` as the penultimate step. (With `TOP`/`LIMIT` being after that) I see your point about ordering by a column you haven't selected but against that you can also order by a column alias defined in the `SELECT` part or a column calculated in the `SELECT` list. I guess this nice neat logical categorisation breaks down a bit here.

Comment: The ordering in this answer is incorrect.  Martin's reference for SQL Server is more reasonable, although it might not be strictly correct for MySQL.

Comment: What @MartinSmith and  @GordonLinoff said. This answer is incorrect. The logical processing order is `FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY`. In MySQL, the `HAVING` can be thought of processed after `SELECT` (so aliases defined in SELECT can be used in HAVING clause, in MySQL).

Comment: If as mentioned here this answer is incorrect, why has it not been eliminated or voted down? It's misleading!