# Mysql use column alias in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql Query:

```
SELECT created_at as date FROM table
```

So I created an alias for the created_at column. Now I want to use this alias in my WHERE clause:

```
SELECT created_at as date FROM table WHERE date = 'xxxx-xx-xx'
```

This does not work. Mysql expects me to use the real column name. Is there any way to do it the way I want to?

Background: I am selecting records from several tables and unite them using `UNION`. All the tables have a date column but it's named different in every table. But I want to do `WHERE` on the united records and therefore I need to have always the same column name

Comment: make a outer select above all unions and then use where with date.

Comment: You cannot use an alias in the clauses of a query like you have done here. You really shouldn't use alias' that are nearly duplicates of keywords either.

Answer (score 1):

You asked, "Is there any way to do it the way I want to?"

Yes, but it requires use of subquery, or a view.

```
SELECT date 
FROM  (SELECT created_at as date FROM table) B
WHERE date = 'xxxx-xx-xx'
```

With the case of a union...

```
SELECT * from (
Select col1, col2,col3 as date from A
union
select col1, col4,col5 from B) inlineView
WHERE date = 'somedate'
```

The problem you're running into is the order of operation within the database.

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

(order taken from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm)
a different order was found [MySQL Order of Operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001183/mysql-order-of-operations)

so now I have to do some research to figure out which one is correct; or if it varies by RDBMS...

So the where clause is executed before the select is evaluated. Thus it doesn't know you aliased it yet.  you can fool the compiler by making the data columns the way you want in the from clause by doing a subselect.

Comment: anymore a CTE (common table expression) would work as well; or a view.  The view could union all the records and then you could select from the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to use your alias as part of the selection criteria, then you need to use `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`

```
SELECT created_at as date FROM table HAVING date = 'xxxx-xx-xx'
```

But it's better to use the column name and `WHERE` because other people reading your code will find the meaning of `WHERE` more obvious than `HAVING`; and it won't use your table indexes as efficiently either

Answer (score 0):

Where doesn't work on aliases.. better you the table_name.column_namem you can use aliases of the columns in group by..

```
  SELECT created_at  FROM table WHERE table.created_at = 'xxxx-xx-xx'  <--more readable, isn't it?
```