# MySQL command: HAVING is to GROUP BY as WHERE is to SELECT?

Tags: mysql, command

Is this true or false ?

```
HAVING is to GROUP BY as WHERE is to SELECT
```

Can someone explain the meaning of this command, thank you!

Comment: yes .. is true,   is the clause for filtering result form aggregated  functions query

Comment: There's some truth in it, but it's far from the whole story

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235152/mysql-use-column-alias-in-where-clause

Answer (score 2):

They really can't be compared like that.

HAVING simply allows you to apply a search to a grouping or aggregate like you would within a WHERE clause.

An Example would be:

```
SELECT StateOfResidence, COUNT(Student) 
FROM Students
GROUP BY StateOfResidence
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Which would return States that had more than one student in them.

You wouldn't be able to say `WHERE COUNT(*) > 1` like you normally can, because you're applying the search to a grouping.