# SQL WHERE does not filter my results

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to filter out results smaller than 3, but whenever I add the WHERE statement the query fails. What is wrong with my query? I am using MySQL Workbench 3.7

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.product_id) AS veggies  
FROM sales AS s
INNER JOIN customers AS c
ON c.id=s.customer_id
GROUP BY s.customer_id
WHERE veggies > 2"
```

Thanks!
Yoni

Comment: Queries have to conform to syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to use `HAVING` after `GROUP BY` not `WHERE`:

```
SELECT 
    c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.product_id) AS veggies
FROM 
    sales AS s
    INNER JOIN customers AS c ON c.id = s.customer_id
GROUP BY 
    s.customer_id
HAVING 
    veggies > 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The `where` should be `having`:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.product_id) AS veggies
FROM sales s INNER JOIN
     customers c
     ON c.id = s.customer_id
GROUP BY s.customer_id
HAVING veggies > 2;
```

Either your query generated a syntax error (i.e., did not run) or it stopped at the `GROUP BY` and ignored the `WHERE`.

Answer (score -1):

[Grouping requires knowledge of entire list. There is an order of operations in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001183/mysql-order-of-operations). (Clicking this link will take you the page which answers that)

This will work hopefully,

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.product_id) AS veggies'  
FROM sales AS s
INNER JOIN customers AS c
ON c.id=s.customer_id
WHERE veggies > "2"
GROUP BY s.customer_id
```

by swapping these two lines.

```
GROUP BY s.customer_id
WHERE veggies > "2"
```

GROUP BY always comes after WHERE.

In addition to this you are missing an opening quote around 2 here.

```
WHERE veggies > 2"
```

And an unnecessary single quote(') at the end of the first line.